# How to add/remove/replace images in a RTF field in Experience Manager?

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

Below is the content of my RTF Field. It consists of an image I need to edit (add/remove/replace) using Experience Manager. Is it possible to to do this in the RTF field? If so, how?

```
<img class="dropshadow image-right" title="text" style="WIDTH: 185px; HEIGHT: 128px"
     alt="Construction" src="tcm:17-1495"/>
<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim  </p>
```

**Code for rendering this component**

```
@if (Fields.sub_copy != null) {
@RenderComponentField("Fields.sub_copy",0,false)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Experience Manager is not such a tool that will allow you to edit multimedia. With experience manager you can do the following things.

- Replace the current Multimedia Component.
- Insert a Multimedia Component.
- Remove the Multimedia Component Reference.
- Apply styles to the image.

Additionally you can add/remove metadata if your multimedia component has been added as a component presentation.

Comment: If we want to replace the current multimedia component as in the code above in RTF field.How can i achieve that?Is is feasible to change in an RTF field?

Comment: you will need to find it in the Library and update it. This action will update the CM side, you will need to update your session preview or publish the page again (Finish Editing) to see the changes in the CM side.